# How to generate Angular 2 projects by default with Angular-Cli (v.1.0.0)

Tags: angular-cli, angular

Now that Angular-Cli v.1.0.0 and Angular v.4.0.0 are official, default project creation with `ng new` generates Angular v.4 project.

For some time I'd still like to create Angular v.2 projects by default. Is there a global config setting of Angular-Cli for that?

**UPDATE:**
Apparently Angular-Cli team rushed for the release and there is a bug. Right now it's not even possible to create an Angular 2 project in command prompt using `--ng2` let along setting it as a global default.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5615) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[They've answered the issue I've created](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5615#issuecomment-289033644), Angular-Cli team won't support creation of Angular 2 projects from v.1.0.0 on.

Those who'd like to create an Angular 2 app with new CLI, just create new project normally and change `package.json` Angular module versions to "older" one that works for you.

Comment: What all should be edited in package.json file of such newly created angular project using latest angular-cli? What's the workflow?

Comment: The section of `package.json` that contains `"dependencies": {`, needs to be edited (with versions for example `2.4.10`, latest of 2.x) instead of default ones that come when you do `ng new ProjectName` (`4.x.x`)

Comment: @Bogac I suppose we do that only for `@angular/*` dependencies. Also, how about *devDependenices*?

Comment: @DilipRajBaral good point. I'd say "same for devDependencies" but one question comes to my mind: Angular Dev Dependencies are mostly CLI related, therefore I don't know how that will work to have latest CLI on your machine but using an older version of related package in project. You need to try.